# Referring to current HTML-Element in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In Razor (MVC 4) can I do something like the following (pseudo)code?

```
<div id="One" @if(THIS_ID_IS("One")) {WRITE_SOMETHING_HERE} ></div>
<div id="Two" @if(THIS_ID_IS("One")) {WRITE_SOMETHING_HERE} ></div>
```

My intention is, that in DIV "One" an additional attribute will be written, but not in DIV "Two"

So, the THIS_ID_IS(string id) should determine, if the Razor-Parse is INSIDE the given DIV with id="xyz"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use single line if statement to overcome this situation

```
<div id="One" @(THIS_ID_IS("One") ? "write something" : "") ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `ids` are `unique` values. All divs will have diffrent ids.
So I dont think there is any need for Conditional Check in razor.

You can Directly add the extra attributes to your `Div` as follows

```
<div id="One" attribute-name="Value"></div>
```

Comment: he's not looking to modify the Id, just add an extra attribute

Comment: Ya But as per his question and his code. we can see at design time only we are knowing what are the `Div ids` inside which we are placing the condition. so my point was there is no need for runtime check as hes not adding the ids dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this I tend to write a helper method to output the markup. This way you a not constrained by the 'rules' of razor. I did a similar thing to output jQuery slider html inside a div.

It also depends on your target audience, I rarely produce the actual views as our designer does most of that. I don't like handing over stuff to the 'creatives' that requires them to write/understand the logic.

It may not be the ideal solution or maybe even overkill in your situation but may be worth a look.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Answer (score 0):

As much as I would like it to be possible. It looks like it's not the case.

Based on these two articles :

- [Simple](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/wiki/1.-About-Razor-and-its-syntax)
- [In depth](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

It would seem that the Razor engine combines a code and a markup parser.
The main parser decides to use one or the other.
So the parsers are not aware of one another.

Simply put, in your example, `<div id="One"></div>` and `@if(THIS_ID_IS("One"))` would be parsed in different scopes and then just concatenated together.